# mysqli bind_result and fetch to PDO PostgreSQL

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to convert my `mysqli` to PDO using PostgreSQL and I am wondering what is the equivalent way of writing the following code in PDO

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($total_rows);
$result->fetch();
```

What I tried is the following:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');
$stmt->execute();
```

but I am not sure how to convert the rest of the `my_sqli` logic to my new PostgreSQL PDO, in particular the `$result->bind_result($total_rows);` and `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO doesn't have anything equivalent to `bind_result()`. `PDOStatement::fetch()` returns the row as an array or object, and you extract the result columns from that. So instead of

```
$result->bind_result($total_rows);
$result->fetch();
echo $total_rows;
```

you use

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

It's generally easier if you assign aliases to the columns being selected, then you can fetch an associative array.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total_rows');
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['total_rows'];
```